# SQL Server sum function give x2 of correct sum value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

The following query which give 400 value of totalDeduction while the tblDeduction table have only 1 deduction with value 200

```
select 
    e.EmpID, concat(e.FName, ' ', e.LName) as Name, 
    o.HireDate, o.BasicPay, s.Scale, 
    SUM(a.amount) as totalAllowance,
    SUM(d.Amount) as totalDeduction
from 
    tblEmployee e, tblEmpOfficialDetail o, tblScale s, tblAllowance a, tblDeduction d  
where 
    e.EmpID = o.EmpID and
    o.ScaleID = s.ID and 
    o.ScaleID = a.ScaleID and 
    o.ScaleID = d.ScaleID 
group by 
    e.EmpID, e.FName, e.LName, o.HireDate, o.BasicPay, s.Scale
```

When I write a separate query using same the logic, it returns the correct ans.

```
select 
    sum(d.amount), o.scale 
from 
    tblDeduction d, tblScale o 
where 
    d.ScaleID = o.ID 
group by 
    o.Scale
```

Please check it

Thanks

Comment: I bet your join conditions are not 1:1, remove the group by to see what's going on. By the way it's recommended to use explicit join syntax, rather than pre-92 implicit syntax.

Comment: SO is for asking questions, not submitting your code for others to fix

Comment: @HoneyBadger what does it mean by "join condition are not 1:1" ? btw when i remove group by clause it give aggregate function error

Comment: @JamesZ i am asking for help , don't know what u get from my question

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @-mac_s i have also tried join syntax but still give same ans

Answer (score 0):

The two queries are not the same because the grouping condition is different.
It may be missing condition that result to inaccurate grouping.

I guessed from the first query that the relation between the tables is like:

```
 tblEmployee e 
    |--> tblEmpOfficialDetail o
           |-->tblDeduction  d
           |-->tblScale      s
           |-->tblAllowance  a
```

Try the next query. It's the same but written as join condition to be sure from the relation between the joined tables.

```
    select e.EmpID, concat(e.FName, ' ', e.LName) as Name , 
    o.HireDate, o.BasicPay, s.Scale, SUM(a.amount) as totalAllowance,SUM(d.Amount) as totalDeduction
    from tblEmployee e
    join  tblEmpOfficialDetail o on e.EmpID=o.EmpID
    join tblDeduction d  on o.ScaleID=d.ScaleID 
    join tblScale s on s.ID=o.ScaleID
    join tblAllowance a on a.ScaleID = o.ScaleID
    group by e.EmpID, e.FName, e.LName, o.HireDate, o.BasicPay, s.Scale
```

Comment: Still give same ans